# HTML Inserting indent

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets file that collects responses from Google Forms. On trigger, the script will send an HTML template and the values from Sheets is pushed using `<?= ?>`.

I tried several ways to add indention but the HTML template seems to ignore it. I have already tried:

- `\t`
- `margin-left`
- `&emsp;`
- spamming space

Can someone please share a workaround? Here is the code snippet:

```
description.push(headers[0][i].replace(*regex*, 'insert-space-here'));
```

Comment: Both `&emsp;` and `&nbsp;` should work in HTML markup, but regular spaces *(leading, trailing etc)* are generally not shown.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the snippet is inside a `for` loop and `if` statement. Only selected values must be indented hence, adding `&emsp;` in the HTML markup is not preferred. I wish to add the indention through the .gs file.

Comment: did you try using the <pre> tag or the <code> tag

Comment: Try using the style tag as suggested by @Cooper. See this [tutorial](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001034.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the elements that you wish to indent a special class and then use css in a style tag. `<style>.myspecialstyle{text-indent:50px;}</style>` Change the Template.

Comment: `function getData(startColumn, endColumn, headers) {
  var description = [];
  for (var i = startColumn; i < (endColumn + 1); i++) {
    if (*regex*.test(headers[0][i])) {
      description.push(headers[0][i].replace(*regex*, '').replace(*regex*, 'insert-space-here'));   
    } else {
      description.push(headers[0][i].replace(*regex*, ''));
    }
  }
  return description;
}`